# How to set tabs line width in vim?

Tags: vim

I have two vertical split windows. I wish to set my tabs line to the width of the first window only, so the newly opened tabs would not overlaps over the second window.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a function that provides a custom tabline, and install it into the `'tabline'` setting. (Note that this won't apply to GVIM with its graphical tabline.)

The help at `:help setting-tabline` has a functioning example that emulates the default tabline. You need to manipulate that to limit the width to that of the first window, which you can retrieve with `winwidth(1)`. To make your tabline also correctly deal with double-width characters, the newish `strdisplaywidth()` function may be of use.

You see, it's doable, but I doubt that the effort warrants the benefit (which I fail to see).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably manipulate the `tabline` (see `:h setting-tabline`) option to achieve your goal but… the tabline already has a very limited usefulness when your reach a dozen tabs because of the available width so it will be even less useful if you reduce it by 50% or more.

What would be the point of that behavior? What would be its benefit? What is your ultimate goal?